# Logo design process templates & tools, multiple font test tool

Tags: typography, text, tools, resource-recommendations

I'm trying to find resources to complete, improve and/or make easy the logo design process using templates based in grids and so on. One of the things I'm trying to find is a webtool or software that automates the process of testing with different fonts like in the picture.

[image: https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/168994423/disp/8ec0f00dcc45fcfa1bf1a9554d66a32a.jpg?cb=1945039031]

Comment: By definition, a logo should *never* use any template or an automated process. You can't create *unique* branding if you are using templates. Almost any font manager application can print sample pages of fonts.

Comment: @Scott I am jot trying to create a logo with a template, I want to automate tasks of the design process.

Comment: We've had clients ask us for this, as if you could put two fonts, three weights, and four colors into a dialog box and have it spit back every possible combination so they could see them all and pick a favorite. One memorable example was doing *eighty-seven* variations on one business card. So I get why you're asking, but no, ya gotta do it by hand.

Comment: What about using Adobe's Typkit to test the text of the logo using their different fonts? They now have both web and desktop use fonts (bundled with Creative Cloud service).

Comment: I'm also wondering how many people will end up with the same logo.

Comment: Good logos aren't made with templates and random lists of fonts.

Comment: @DA01 No one asked for templates and random lists, please read the question. I want to know about tools to speed up the process like a template in which is possible to put together different (previously chosen) fonts, so it is easier to compare.

Comment: @Kevin are you asking for software to create a font specimen book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely understand what you are looking for and why. I recently read in the book, Logo Creed, a section about the process of logo designer Brian Miller.

He uses Freehand MX to do exactly what you are asking.

I have just started to search for this outdated program to see if it is possible to load it onto a modern mac without issues. (Let me know if you have any luck with this. I'd love to save the time in the font exploration phase as well).

Comment: Freehand is dead.

Comment: And Freehand didn't offer anything special with respect to this. You could do the same thing in Illustrator most likely.

Comment: Freehand MX - wow brings back memories! I'm sure that's an old book and Brian Miller probably uses Illustrator now.

Answer (score 1):

There *are* programs that do exactly this...generate logos from templates and lists of fonts. Here's one for example:

http://www.logomaker.com/

And some of the "logos" you can make using it:

[image]

Are these good logos? Impossible to say without knowing a lot more about the customer and their needs. I think most professional designers would argue that these are very formulaic, not terribly interesting, and generally boring. But sometimes that's all a client needs.

Tools like this certainly speed up the number of objects you can spit out, but I wouldn't say they improve the logo creation process. In fact, I'd say they get in the way of that. Creating a logo is about solving a problem via a very targeted solution. These software tools instead just throw random solutions at the wall hoping one sticks.

Comment: I'm not trying to generate logos from templates, I'm trying to automate the process of generating font lists and other repetitive parts of the logo design process.

Comment: @Kevin I think what you are looking for is a tool to create a font specimen book from your installed fonts. But that's not particular to Logo design. So maybe I just don't quite understand what you are looking for. Typically, I choose fonts, and then use them in the logo. I may choose 2 or 3, but I don't need to automate that. I simply create the 3 logo variations.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the [Google Fonts web tool](https://www.google.com/fonts#ChoosePlace:select) and type the name in the field "Preview Text".
2. Or use the well known [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=101) website, you can type the name in the field "Preview" (when a category is selected).